# Own Bundle Product

Tags: commerce

My product (commerce product) is referencing through the field node_pro_ref -> Nodes which are Product displays.
When the product is paid, all nodes (product displays) which are referenced through the field node_pro_ref, should be also available for current user as paid.

Field node_pro_ref is of entity reference field type (which referencing nodes)

Of course, Product Display is referencing one product which is product of type 2. 
It is similar as bundle product.

I'm trying to create some rule, acting on a event **When the order is first paid in full**
Is it correct? I don't what to do next.
It looks like that:
[image: bundle product]